# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null at HTMLInputElement.func1

Tags: javascript

Где ошибка в коде? В консоле пишет: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
    at HTMLInputElement.func1

```js
// получаем все значения ползунков и присваиваем обработчик
document.getElementById("rtl").addEventListener("input", func1);
document.getElementById("rtr").addEventListener("input", func1);
document.getElementById("rbr").addEventListener("input", func1);
document.getElementById("rbl").addEventListener("input", func1);

function func1() {
 // ползунки
 var rtl = document.getElementById("rtl").value;
 var rtr = document.getElementById("rtr").value;
 var rbr = document.getElementById("rbr").value;
 var rbl = document.getElementById("rbl").value;

 // окно с текстом
 var ttl = document.getElementById("ttl");
 var ttr = document.getElementById("ttr");
 var tbr = document.getElementById("tbr");
 var tbl = document.getElementById("tbl");

 // наша фигура
 var block = document.getElementById("block");

 // окно принимает значение ползунка
 ttl.value = rtl;
 ttr.value = rtr;
 tbr.value = rbr;
 tbl.value = rbl;

 // задаем стиль блока
 block.style.borderRadius = rtl + "px " + rtr + "px " + rbr + "px " + rbl + "px";
 console.log(block.style.borderRadius);
}
```

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

.block {
 width: 200px;
 height: 100px;
 background-color: #1eb377;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="block1">
  <p>Верхний левый угол
   <!-- rtl - range top left -->
   <input type="range" id="rtl" min="0" max="100" value="0">
   <!-- ttl - text top left -->
   <input type="text" id="ttl" value="0">
  </p>
  <p>Верхний правый угол
   <!-- rtr - range top right -->
   <input type="range" id="rtr" min="0" max="100" value="0">
   <!-- ttr - text top right -->
   <input type="text" id="ttr" value="0">
  </p>
  <p>Нижний правый угол
   <!-- rbr - range bottom right -->
   <input type="range" id="rbr" min="0" max="100" value="0">
   <!-- tbr - text bottom right -->
   <input type="text" id="tbr" value="0">
  </p>
  <p>Нижний левый угол
   <!-- rbl - range bottom left -->
   <input type="range" id="rbl" min="0" max="100" value="0">
   <!-- tbl - text bottom left -->
   <input type="text" id="tbl" value="0">
  </p>
 </div>
 <div class="block">
  
 </div>
 <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `<div class="block">` => `<div id="block">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет элемента с `id="block"`.

```
var block = document.querySelector(".block");
```

```js
// получаем все значения ползунков и присваиваем обработчик
document.getElementById("rtl").addEventListener("input", func1);
document.getElementById("rtr").addEventListener("input", func1);
document.getElementById("rbr").addEventListener("input", func1);
document.getElementById("rbl").addEventListener("input", func1);

function func1() {
 // ползунки
 var rtl = document.getElementById("rtl").value;
 var rtr = document.getElementById("rtr").value;
 var rbr = document.getElementById("rbr").value;
 var rbl = document.getElementById("rbl").value;

 // окно с текстом
 var ttl = document.getElementById("ttl");
 var ttr = document.getElementById("ttr");
 var tbr = document.getElementById("tbr");
 var tbl = document.getElementById("tbl");

 // наша фигура
 var block = document.querySelector(".block");

 // окно принимает значение ползунка
 ttl.value = rtl;
 ttr.value = rtr;
 tbr.value = rbr;
 tbl.value = rbl;

 // задаем стиль блока
 block.style.borderRadius = rtl + "px " + rtr + "px " + rbr + "px " + rbl + "px";
 console.log(block.style.borderRadius);
}
```

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

.block {
 width: 200px;
 height: 100px;
 background-color: #1eb377;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="block1">
  <p>Верхний левый угол
   <!-- rtl - range top left -->
   <input type="range" id="rtl" min="0" max="100" value="0">
   <!-- ttl - text top left -->
   <input type="text" id="ttl" value="0">
  </p>
  <p>Верхний правый угол
   <!-- rtr - range top right -->
   <input type="range" id="rtr" min="0" max="100" value="0">
   <!-- ttr - text top right -->
   <input type="text" id="ttr" value="0">
  </p>
  <p>Нижний правый угол
   <!-- rbr - range bottom right -->
   <input type="range" id="rbr" min="0" max="100" value="0">
   <!-- tbr - text bottom right -->
   <input type="text" id="tbr" value="0">
  </p>
  <p>Нижний левый угол
   <!-- rbl - range bottom left -->
   <input type="range" id="rbl" min="0" max="100" value="0">
   <!-- tbl - text bottom left -->
   <input type="text" id="tbl" value="0">
  </p>
 </div>
 <div class="block">
  
 </div>
 <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Заработало, спасибо